# Switching between day and night themes in android 6 using AppCompat

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-theme

I'm using the new Theme.AppCompat.DayNight in appcompat 23.3.0. I have tried using the following to switch between day/night/auto in a settings activity of my app:

```
themePref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(App.getNightModeInt((String) newValue));
        getActivity().recreate();
        return true;
    }
});
```

This works as expected on API22 and below. However on android 6, switching between day and night mode results in the listperference dialog being incorrectly themed.

[image]

Here is the code for a sample application which displays the issue: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4S9C9b4mk9SZlhoXzVJa1ZiUGc/view?usp=sharing

How do you enable switching between day and night mode from settings, which works in all versions of android?

Comment: I've opened a bug report here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=206573

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same issue.